# Javascript синхронизация вкладок Tab браузера.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Каким образом можно реализовать синхронизацию вкладок браузера? То есть допустим я открыл 3 вкладки одного и того же сайта. На одной из них нажал на кнопку, и во всех трех вкладках произошел к примеру alert('Hello');

Пробовал найденный в сети способ через EventListener к LocalStorage, но работает это через раз, и не во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 2):

Для синхронизации вкладок удобно использовать [storage event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-event):

```
window.addEventListener('storage', sync);
function sync(event) {
    if (event.key == 'name') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Если требуется очень сложная синхронизация вкладок, то лучшей практикой является простое уведомление пользователя о произошедших изменениях в других вкладках с просьбой перезагрузить страницу.

Comment: Решил использовать ваш метод, но немного по своему     window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
        if (e.key == 'reload') {
            location.reload();
        }
    }); , если ввести в консоли браузера localStorage.setItem('reload', 'true); - вкладки перезагружаются. Если этот код выполнять непосредственно в js файлах, ничего не происходит. Не подскажите почему ?

Comment: @Владимир 1. Фоновая перезагрузка вкладок не очень хорошая идея, лучше манипулировать DOM. 2. Метод не стабилен и нуждается в тщательном тестировании. 3. Нет кавычки после `'true`

Comment: В моем случае более приемлимо перезагружать вкладки. Кавычки стоят, это я просто невнимательно написал коммент. Раз метод не стабилен, и работает не всегда, не знаете аналогичного решения?

Comment: @Владимир 1. Storage + проверка по таймеру. 2. Cookie + проверка по таймеру. 3. Broadcast Channel API.

Comment: Спасибо, вы не в курсе, нет ли чего-либо на подобии Listener, к примеру для куки, чтобы циклом не проверять каждый раз. Ну или к тому же Storage, но корректно рабочий.

Comment: @Владимир Вышеупомянутый `storage event` и `cookies.onChanged`